having functions that use bpy in different python files
I'm trying to split my code into multiple python files for readability and ease of use.
In my main file, in addition to other things, i import bpy and I import all from functions.py
import bpy
from functions import *

in functions.py, i have a function which calls bpy and I get the error:
NameError: name 'bpy' is not defined

if I copy that script back into my main python script it works fine, is there any way to use bpy in separate python files like this?
Edit:
Sorry, i discovered my problem was unrelated to what I posted here. The real issue was that it wasn't re-importing the updated functions, so even though I was making changes to the functions.py doc, it wasn't actually showing any updates so it didn't fix the error when I added import bpy to function.py, but did see the updated when I added the code back into the main script.
The solution was to add these lines:
import functions
import importlib
importlib.reload(functions)
from functions import *


This is not about Blender, but rather basic Python module usage and scope hierarchy.

In most python scripts I can put the includes in the functions file and it works fine, with bpy specifically that doesn't appear to work

What do you mean, "That doesn't appear to work"? Importing a module and then trying to use it can never result in a NameError unless you did something like import bpy as cantfindme, or from bpy import * then bpy.someAttribute instead of just someAttribute.

bpy is not defined in functions.py because you never imported it in functions.py; only in your main module, which is above it in the hierarchy. Scope is not transferred to imported modules from the modules that imported them.
If trying to import bpy in functions.py results in a ModuleNotFoundError, describe that problem instead.

Sorry, i edited my question with the real answer to my issue, which was completely unrelated to my question. The problem was that it wasn't reloading my functions.py functions when i re-ran the main code

Don’t edit an answer into a question ‍♂️ Please, read https://stackexchange.com/tour and https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour
